# Foreground service starting new activity before current activity saves information

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, sharedpreferences

My app's main activity is launched from a foreground service notification using a pending intent. This works as expected. However, the new activity is launched before information gets saved if the user already has the main activity open.

Scenario: Main activity is open and the foreground service is running. The user has made some changes to text in the main activity and then decides (for whatever reason) to hit the notification of the foreground service. This launches the main activity again. However the new instance's `onStart()` and `onResume()` are called *before* the previous instance's `onSavedInstanceState()` or `onStop()` are called.

Result: The user looses the work they had done on the main activity prior to hitting the notification.

How do I prevent this data from being lost? Is there a way to ensure it gets saved (I'm using shared preferences) before the new instance is opened from the notification?

I'm surprised the new instance's `onResume()` is called before the previous instance's `onSaveInstanceState()`. I've looked into using `onPause()`, but the documentation discourages saving data there.

Comment: Why do you launch the MainActivity again? Why not just return to the existing MainActivity if the user clicks on a Notification? That would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responses provided two great tips which I was able to implement in various forms. The [first from Tenten Ponce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070172/9111313) was to save information as it was created. In my case I don't have text data being input from a user that would require a `TextWatcher`, but I did implement a means to save the data to `sharedPreferences` in real time when it made sense.

Thanks to [David Wasser's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48070035/9111313) on the original question, I also added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` which worked perfectly. This attribute seemed to make the most sense in my application based on [this API guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about limiting your MainActivity to a Single Instance in the Manifest by setting launchMode="singleTask"

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Save the data real time.** 

When the user inputs, save it immediately on your `sharedPreferences` using `TextWatcher()` (if you're using `EditText`). Then on the activity `onResume()`, pre-fill the information that exists on your `sharedPreferences`.

*I didn't provide a code because you also didn't provide any codes.*

Comment: Why do you launch the `MainActivity` again? Why not just return to the existing `MainActivity` if the user clicks on a `Notification`? That would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I think that will be good if he can check if the `activity` is in `foreground`, and simply dismiss the notification. Your idea is better sir.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment on the original question, not on your answer